# Body send but not received

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hey i use a react app for call a express app:

```
fetch('/api/sendmail', {method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(payload) })
```

Payload =

```
    const payload = {
        fsdfdsdfsdfsdsfa: 1,
        b: 2
    };
```

On express app i try to get body content:

```
app.post("/api/sendmail", (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body)
   res.json({ message: 'aa' });
});
```

but `console.log(req.body)` return undefined

How i can resolve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume you simply missing something like this in your init file:

`app.use(bodyparser.json())`

Also try adding `Content-Type: application/json` as your request header

Answer (score 0):

I think for express to be able to parse POST requests you need a body-parser middleware.

```js
    var express = require('express')
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    
    var app = express()

    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

    app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
        res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
    })
```

You will have to install ["body-parser"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) though. I heard express comes with it's own [body-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) now but I have no info on that so you will have to read the docs